# Enabling automatic deduction of template argument type based on that argument's default value

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Here's what I want to do:

```
#include <vector>

template <class ContainerType, typename ComparatorType>
void f(
    ContainerType c1,
    ComparatorType comp = 
    [](const typename ContainerType::value_type& l, const typename ContainerType::value_type& r) {return l < r;})
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2};
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work: `could not deduce template argument for 'ComparatorType'`.

Using a proxy function instead of an actual default argument value works, but seems overly verbose, isn't there a better way? Not to mention it's not the same since now I can't just substitute the default comparator with my own without changing the function name in the client code.

```
#include <vector>

template <class ContainerType, typename ComparatorType>
void f(
    ContainerType c1,
    ComparatorType comp)
{
}

template <class ContainerType>
void f2(ContainerType c)
{
    f(c, [](const typename ContainerType::value_type& l, const typename ContainerType::value_type& r) {return l < r;});
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2};
    f2(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to nail down the exact type of the comparison function object in the template signature? Sounds to me that `template <class ContainerType, typename ComparatorType = std::less<>> void f(...)`  might do want you want, too?!

Comment: @lubgr: I was thinking about `std::less<>` as well, but I don't see how that circumvents the problem, it's just a different default type.

Comment: Don't you want to accept the container by reference?

Comment: @rustyx: not in this particular case, the function will be sorting its local copy of the container. But good point there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template deduction is performed before default arguments are considered. Also, lambdas are not allowed to appear in unevaluated operands.

You can first assign the default function to a variable. Then you can spell out its type. For example:

```
auto default_functor = [](int x){ return x > 0; };

template <typename T, typename F = decltype(default_functor)>
auto function(T x, F f = default_functor)
{
  return f(x);
}
```

Now you can use the function as usual:

```
bool even(int x)
{
  return x % 2 == 0;
}

struct Odd {
  bool operator()(int x) const
  {
    return x % 2 == 1;
  }
};

void g()
{
  function(1); // use default functor
  function(1, even); // use a free function
  function(1, Odd{}); // use a function object
  function(1, [](int x){ return x < 0; }); // use another lambda
}
```

You don't need to explicitly specify the type.

---

Note: According to [@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller), this can lead to ODR violation if you use it in a header. In that case, you can use a named functor type:

```
struct Positive {
    constexpr bool operator(int x) const
    {
        return x > 0;
    }
};

inline constexpr Positive default_functor{};

template <typename T, typename F = decltype(default_functor)>
auto function(T x, F f = default_functor)
{
  return f(x);
}
```

Comment: That would work, but then if I want to pass a second argument, I'll need to manually specify its type? Cumbersome for lambdas especially.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe What do you mean by "manually specify its type?"

Comment: I mean that I can't do `f(container, std::less<>{})`, I'll need `f<decltype(container), std::less<>>(container, std::less<>{})`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes, you can. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! I was certain that specifying a default type disables automatic type deduction for that argument. I find it weird that it doesn't, but good to know!

Comment: I have a strong suspicion this is an ODR violation. Every TU that includes the above header (assuming it's in a header) will have a different default argument for `F`.

Comment: @StoryTeller If it is a header which will be included in multiple TUs, you should mark the declaration as `extern` and define it in a separate TU.

Comment: @L.F. - And what type do you give that extern variable? You got yourself a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: If you *really* want this to work, you *can't* use a lambda. Only doing something like `struct default_functor { auto operator() (int x){ return x > 0; } };` and `F = default_functor` is gonna be truly without issues.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah. Maybe this problem fell out of the scope of lambda ... It is just a syntactic sugar anyway ... If the default function deserves to be in a header, declaring a dedicated type may be a better choice, anyway.

Comment: Maybe. Regardless, since this is the accepted answer, the one that most readers will stop at, you should edit it to not have a brittle solution. Use a named function type instead. And we should let @VioletGiraffe know before they encounter any issues.

Comment: @StoryTeller Done.

Comment: @StoryTeller: good thinking. The way I circumvented this problem is by using `std::less<>` as the default type since my original functor was superfluous to begin with.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - Yeah, that'll do. `ComparatorType = std::less<>` and `comp = {}` pair up nicely and robustly. +1 for reusing the standard library :)

Answer (score 5):

> without changing the function name in the client code.

You can overload function templates just fine. There is no need to use a different name.

```
template <class ContainerType, typename ComparatorType>
void f(
    ContainerType c1,
    ComparatorType comp)
{
}

template <class ContainerType>
void f(ContainerType c)
{
    f(c, [](const typename ContainerType::value_type& l, const typename ContainerType::value_type& r) {return l < r;});
}
```

You can't make a default function argument contribute to template argument deduction. It's not allowed because it raises some difficult to resolve questions in the deduction process.